# git - fetch an intermediate commit

Tags: git

Is there any git command to fetch an intermediate commit, just like 'svn co -r xxx' works? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872486/pull-a-specific-commit-from-a-remote-git-repository

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`git checkout <commit-id>`, where `<commit-id>` is the SHA1 of a commit, a tag, or a branch.

Note that in git vocabulary, `fetch` refers to connecting to a remote repository and grabbing its commits.

Comment: Thanks! So, is it possible checkout a specified folder to that commit, but leave others unchanged?

Comment: @soul2003: well, you can - e.g. `git checkout <commit-id> -- tests/` will revert your working tree (and the staging area) for the `tests` subdirectory to the state at `<commit-id>`.  However, asking that question raises the larger one of "what problem are you really trying to solve?" - I suspect that's not what you really want to do...

Comment: @soul2003: I find "can you x?" questions in git easiest to look up in the [visual git reference](http://marklodato.github.com/visual-git-guide/index-en.html).