# git pull from remote... can I pull a specific commit?

Tags: git, github, fetch, pull

I create an empty new repository locally, I add a remote repository.
Now I want to get a specific commit from the remote repository **without downloading the whole remote repository with all its branches!**

How do I do that?

Comment: True, maybe this one: `git fetch origin 96de5297df870:refs/remotes/origin/D-commit`

Comment: Why do I get downvotes? The title of the duplicate entry does not contain the word 'git', so I didn't find it!

Comment: it doesn't have to, you should use tags in your search.

Comment: The marked duplicate does not answer my question. It allows to fetch a specific commit, but it also downloads THE WHOLE repository from remote. I clearly asked for a solution where it does NOT DOWNLOAD the whole repo first and then does the fetch of a specific commit. How can I remove the [duplicate] in the title? It's just not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is

```
git fetch origin 96de5297df870:refs/remotes/origin/D-commit
```

See [Retrieve specific commit from a remote Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872486/pull-a-specific-commit-from-a-remote-repository)

Comment: This command only seems to work when I already have that commit hash locally, so it can create a remote reference but it can't seem to fetch anything new. Does it work for anyone else?

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me either.

Comment: It doesn't work if the commit is not already in the repository. It prints nothing but gives back an exit code 1.

Comment: This works for me and I use it regularly.