# How can I view and pull previous remote branch push?

Tags: git, logging, version, push

Say I have a branch that is called `branch1`. I have made few merges and pushes (on various dates) in order to save my changes on the remote repo, for example:

On Dec 16:

```
git merge -am "branch1 comment1"  
git push origin branch1
```

On Dec 17:

```
git merge -am "branch1 comment2"  
git push origin branch1
```

On Dec 18:

```
git merge -am "branch1 comment3"  
git push origin branch1
```

1. How can I list/view the history of branch 1 on the REMOTE (list of the 3 above versions, dates and comments)?

   I tried unsuccessfully `git show -r branch1`, `git ls-remote origin branch1` and `git log origin/branch1`...
2. How can I pull the version of Dec 17 of branch 1?

I also looked at [Retrieve specific commit from a remote Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872486/pull-a-specific-commit-from-a-remote-repository) and related ones but I could not find simple short answer.

Comment: Also, while I was trying to figure this out, I deleted branch1 locally using "git branch -D branch1" ... but it exists on the remote repo

Answer (score 0):

You can list the local tracking branch

```
git log origin/branch1
```