# Github delete branch even after made commits to it?

Tags: github, branch

I have a github repo and I am working on the site, I don't know how to do command line stuff.

So I have a branch I made commits too. And I see it can be deleted. This is kind of nice. I always do small unit tests and just want to delete it. So if I do delete a branch is all traces and history of it gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a local repo anymore (meaning you cannot get your deleted branch through the local git reflog and push it back to GitHub), you still can retrieve (for a limited time, 90 days by default), your deleted branch from the GitHub repo itself.

See the [GitHub Events API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/).
Those events are limited in time, so "all traces and history of it gone?": yes, eventually.

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/events
```

As described in [this blog post](http://www.objectpartners.com/2014/02/11/recovering-a-commit-from-githubs-reflog/), you will get a JSON payload which will include any [push event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent) you ever made, including your old branch:

```
    "id": "1970551769",
    "type": "PushEvent",
    "actor": {
      "id": 563541,
      "login": "<user>",
      "gravatar_id": "<id>",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/<user>",
      "avatar_url": "<url>"
    },
    "repo": {
      "id": 9652839,
      "name": "<user>/<repo>",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>"
    },
    "payload": {
      "push_id": 303837533,
      "size": 1,
      "distinct_size": 1,
      "ref": "refs/heads/<branch>",  <============================
      "head": "a973ddd28d599c9ba128de56182f8769d2b9843b",
      "before": "4ef3d74316c04c892d17250f0ba251b328274e5f",
      "commits": [
        {
          "sha": "384f275933d5b762cdb27175aeff1263a8a7b7f7",
          "author": {
            "email": "<email>",
            "name": "<author>"
          },
          "message": "<commit message>",
          "distinct": true,
          "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/commits/384f275933d5b762cdb27175aeff1263a8a7b7f7"
        }
      ]
    },
    "public": false,
    "created_at": "2014-02-06T14:05:17Z"
}
```

You can then [fetch, using that specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14872590/6309) '`a973ddd28d599c9ba128de56182f8769d2b9843b`', make a branch locally and push it back to GitHub!

```
git fetch origin a973ddd28d599c9ba128de56182f8769d2b9843b:refs/remotes/origin/yourOldBranch
git checkout -b yourOldBranch
git push
```

Comment: Oh wow this is such great info. Thanks man. So to verify/sum it up after 90 days it is permanently deleted huh meaning all traces? And before those 90 days it is possible to get it back.

Comment: @Noitidart 90 days is the default before `gc` (garbage collector) is run. But GitHub might have a different policy.

Comment: Thanks for your detail. I read the blog and your detail on using the `head` value is great to emphasize. Thanks again man!