# Git fetch a single commit

Tags: git, github

I would like to fetch a single commit (with history, of course) of a remote repository into a local one. Some Stack Overflow responses suggest that the following should work, but it does not:

```
md foo
cd foo
git init
git fetch https://github.com/ld4apps/lda-serverlib.git f1e32e18a90e10c150221af55c69aeafaa42c57a
```

This produces the following error:

> error: no such remote ref f1e32e18a90e10c150221af55c69aeafaa42c57a

Surprisingly (to me) the following does (sort of) work:

```
git fetch https://github.com/ld4apps/lda-serverlib.git :f1e32e18a90e10c150221af55c69aeafaa42c57a
```

This creates a new local branch called `f1e32e18a90e10c150221af55c69aeafaa42c57a` (which I did not want), but at least the new branch has the contents I was trying to fetch. I might have expected that the following command would do the same thing, but it gets the same error as the first example:

```
git fetch https://github.com/ld4apps/lda-serverlib.git f1e32e18a90e10c150221af55c69aeafaa42c57a:f1e32e18a90e10c150221af55c69aeafaa42c57a
```

I tried this on Windows and Linux with a couple of different git versions and saw the same behavior.

Can anyone explain what is going on here? What am I not understanding about Git, `fetch`, and refspecs? What I really want is a single `git fetch` command to which I can provide either the id of a remote branch or tag or a commit id and it will fetch the corresponding commit.

Comment: What does “a single commit with history” mean? The other commits are the history…

Comment: I just mean the usual git behavior, nothing special. I want to fetch a particular commit, and I understand that git will also fetch the commits that constitute the history for the commit I specify.

Comment: Well, it won’t if you use `git fetch --depth=1` (and that does happen to work, since f1e32e18a90e10c150221af55c69aeafaa42c57a is the current tip for your example, but that’s not the question, is it?).

Comment: I wasn't aware of the depth option - thanks for the info. As you say, although interesting, that doesn't seem pertinent to my question

Comment: Isn't this Q a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872486/pull-a-specific-commit-from-a-remote-git-repository ?

Comment: Should the github tag be removed? It makes the page title confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: since Git 2.5 (mid-2015 or so), servers now *may* expose raw hashes.  This is a server-side configuration item.  You must have sufficient control on the server to set it, and you should consider potential security issues before you do set it.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30701724/135889) to [Retrieve specific commit from a remote Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14872486/1256452) for details.  (Original answer, which applies to pre-2.5 or if the configuration knob is not set, below.)

---

The `git fetch` command delivers *references* (names, not raw commit-IDs) to the remote, more or less.  (More specifically, use `git ls-remote remotename` to see what the remote is willing to give you in terms of names.  This produces a list of SHA-1s on the left with names on the right, and the only thing your `fetch` can *ask* for is the names-on-the-right.  At which point you'll get the ID-on-the-left *if* the name on the remote still points to that ID, so it depends on how actively that remote gets updated.)

It is possible, in various ways, to deliver raw commit-IDs to a remote and ask that remote what is visible starting from that point, and sometimes working backwards through history as well, but not via `git fetch`.  (You can use `git archive` but the remote can decide whether or not to allow you to access via raw commit-IDs; or with remotes that have web server access, including to specific commits, you can often just view the top-level contents of a commit, and use that to "drill down", as they say, to the various pieces.  But that is a very slow way to do it.)

If you'd like to use `git fetch` to get some particular commit, probably the easiest way to do that is to have someone with access to the remote attach a name—most likely a tag—to that commit ID.  Then you can have your `git fetch` bring over that refspec, and put it under any other refspec you like.  For instance, suppose you can ssh directly to whatever hosts `origin`:

```
$ ssh our.origin.host 'cd /repos/repo.git; git tag temporary f1e32e1'
[enter password, etc; observe tag created]
$ git fetch origin refs/tags/temporary:refs/heads/newbranch
[observe fetch happen; now you have local branch 'newbranch']
$ ssh our.origin.host 'cd /repos/repo.git; git tag -d temporary'
```

Note that the name need not be a branch, it need only be a reference you can pull over with `git fetch` and see with `git ls-remote`.  You then use a name that will match that on the left-hand-side of your refspec when fetching.  The name created in *your* repo is controlled by the right-hand-side of the refspec (`refs/heads/newbranch` in the example above).

This is also the answer to your last paragraph question: you can only name things that have names on the remote (this is partly intended to avoid "leaking" unnamed commits that remain in a repository before garbage-collection, so it's considered a feature rather than a bug).  These names go on the LHS of the refspec.  Your own names go on the right.

Your name on the right is assumed to be a branch or tag name (based on what the name on the left matches, though you can explicitly spell out `refs/heads/` or `refs/tags/` to override it), so even though `f1e32e1...` is a valid SHA-1, it's treated as a branch name here—the missing name on the left translates to `HEAD`, as missing names almost always do—and `git fetch` creates a branch whose name is disturbingly SHA-1-ish.  (Incidentally I once created a branch name that looked like an SHA-1, and later confused myself.  I forget exactly what the name was, something like `de-bead` without the hyphen. I renamed it to the hyphenated version just to make it clear I didn't mean a raw commit ID! :-) )

Comment: Thanks, Torek, that is helpful and seems to explain most of what I saw. I don't see that it explains why/how
<code>
git fetch https://github.com/ld4apps/lda-serverlib.git :f1e32e18a90e10c150221af55c69aeafaa42c57a
</code>
worked. What is going on there?

Comment: Added a last paragraph with "intent".  Will see if I can clarify the branch-creating...

Comment: Perhaps I'm being dull here. I understand that the RHS controls my own names, so I'm not surprised that 'git fetch repo :f1e32e18a90e10c150221af55c69aeafaa42c57a' created a local branch named f1e32e18a90e10c150221af55c69aeafaa42c57a. What does surprise me is that it also fetched the commit of the same id on the remote, even though that commit was not addressable when I put it on the LHS.

Comment: Ah, it was the empty LHS that confused you.  See re-edited last paragraph.

Comment: Note: [this appears to be possible now, if the server is configured to allow it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30701724/135889).