# Pull a commit from a Gerrit repository using its commit ID only

Tags: git, gerrit

Let's assume I have the SHA1 of a commit that's under code review in Gerrit, but not its reference (refs/changes/...)

The question is: how to fetch it from my local repository?

There is a similar question yet Gerrit-unrelated question here: [Retrieve specific commit from a remote Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872486/pull-a-specific-commit-from-a-remote-git-repository)

The answer doesn't seem to work with Gerrit:

```
git fetch origin 67b4b77655d65004cc908aaf7e65b24bcaa81fd8:refs/remotes/origin/foo
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref 67b4b77655d65004cc908aaf7e65b24bcaa81fd8
```

I can see the commit though if I use git ls-remote:

```
git ls-remote | grep 67b4b77655d65004cc908aaf7e65b24bcaa81fd8
From ssh://gerrit/repo
67b4b77655d65004cc908aaf7e65b24bcaa81fd8        refs/changes/...
```

So it looks like Gerrit somehow doesn't look in refs/changes/ during the explicit fetch.

Of course, as a workaround, I can fetch the commit using its refs/changes/... reference, but I was wondering if there is a more direct way, and more importantly, when Gerrit doesn't find the commit when referred to directly by its SHA1.

Comment: Have you tried checking it out first? `git chekcout SHA1`

Comment: Yes, it's not in the local repository.

Comment: in git config the _remote.origin.fetch_ param probably contains `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` but Gerrit commits stored under `refs/changes/<changeid>` that is why I think you need to know the specific refs to able to fetch it

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but that was already clear to me that I can fetch with the reference. The question is: how to fetch using the ID directly?

Comment: Related discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/Kn1n-DTcjl8

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have (almost) answered your own question.

```
git ls-remote | grep 67b4b77655d65004cc908aaf7e65b24bcaa81fd8 |  awk '{system("git fetch origin " $2)}' && git checkout 67b4b77655d65004cc908aaf7e65b24bcaa81fd8
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am actually more curious why Gerrit doesn't find a valid commit unless a reference is given, and how to change that. I am not looking for a pragmatical solution, more for an explanation.