# Pulling a specific version with git

Tags: git, github

I need the source code from a specific version of a project (The [SonarQube](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube) project), but I can't figure out how to pull it from git.

I've added the repo as a remote (`git add remote origin`) and pulled the latest version from the master branch, but that is not the version I need.

I know the commit I need is `d25bc0e`, but when I try "`git fetch origin master d25bc0e`" I get the error "`fatal: couldn't find remote ref d25bc0e`".

It could be I'm doing something very wrong, I am not very experienced with Git.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You cannot pull a specific commit.

See more at "[Pull a specific commit from a remote git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14872590/6309)"

Once cloned, you can checkout a specific commit (but you would be in a [detached branch mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309), which is ok if all you need to do is read, and not commit)

```
git checkout d25bc0e
```

If you had to do some modification, starting from that commit, you would create a new branch:

```
git checkout -b newBranch d25bc0e
```

---

Note: since Oct. 2014, you might be able to [fetch only one commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30701724/6309) (Git 2.5, June 2015), only if the remote server allows it.
But here, I would still recommend the classic workflow (clone+checkout).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the specific version. You can get it via commit id.

You can get the commit id in logs.

So first try **git log** to get specific commit id

Then try

git reset --hard commit_id

But this will not allow you to commit the version. This is read only of a specific version.