# Fetch specific commit from remote git repo

Tags: git, git-fetch

So, what I'm basically trying to do is to pull down a given commit (identified by its SHA) from one remote repo, and then push it to another remote repo as a new branch (whose name I autogenerate). The source repo will vary and these are all one-shot operations, so I don't want to `git remote add` these remotes and I don't want to create refs/branches for the commits. And I don't want to change the HEADs of any of my local branches.

So, **how do I just grab the given remote commit (and any of its parent commits that are new to me) and add it/them to my local git database?**

`git pull` implicitly involves a merge or rebase, so that's out of the question.

I tried `git fetch https://github.com/foo/bar.git 7d0969daba1fdf9d5bb9bc9a2847fd1bc1c7e426`
but that just leads to
`error: no such remote ref 12819ad8e10e5906df5352d7d8fec1fceb1f3afc`
(and yes, I verified that that commit SHA exists on that remote; looks like git doesn't accept a SHA here anyway).

I mean, I guess I could come up with a single arbitrary local branch name to always pull the commits down into, and then delete that branch after every push, but that's seems inelegant...

Comment: Git fetch can't fetch by SHA by design.  I don't see any solution other than creating and deleting branches.

Comment: @AndrewC If you repost that as an answer, I would happily mark it as accepted.

Comment: IT sounds like a duplicate but i can't find anything exact so I'll add it

Comment: Since Git 2.5 it's possible to fetch a specific commit, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30701724/537554

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve specific commit from a remote Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872486/retrieve-specific-commit-from-a-remote-git-repository)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git does not allow you to fetch by SHA by design.  It doesn't seem like there are any plans to enable that either based on previous conversations on the developers [mailing list](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Fetch-by-SHA-missing-td5604552.html)

You will have to have a reference on the remote in order to be able to fetch.  You should be able to auto-generate this part I would imagine, since you have to have a mechanism to pass the remote and sha back and forth already.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git fetch` to get all commits from your `origin` repository. Then, create a branch on the desired commit

```
git branch theBranch 7d0969dab
```

Now, you can push this branch to the second repo

```
git push https://github.com/secondRepo/bar.git theBranch:theRemoteBranchNameYouWant
```