# Updating to a specific commit id in GIT

Tags: git

I am moving from SVN to GIT. Usually while deploying the package, the working directory is updated to a particular revision <= HEAD but always greater than the current revision of the working copy. so in SVN it is simple, just updating to a specific revision

Suppose current revision of working directory - 34500 and HEAD is at 34600, and packagae needs to be deployed for 34576. So, in SVN simply

```
svn update -r34576
```

and when a new package needs to be created for a higher revision, we simply move to a higher revision, like

```
svn update -r34589
```

Now, trying to do the same in GIT. Package needs to created from master. But not necessary uptil the HEAD. Is this what I am suposed to do:

```
git checkout 3ef0d...
```

or

```
 git pull --rebase origin master
 git checkout 3ef0d...
```

And similarly when I want it for a higher commit id/revison

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872486/pull-a-specific-commit-from-a-remote-git-repository

Comment: @Nick I'm not so sure that covers the entire question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say - hypothetically - that this is the output you get from `git log --graph --oneline`.

```
* de65bbf < HEAD
* 189ca83
* 40c918c
*   5497694
|\  
| * 5295fe4
* | 7879de1
|/  
* 61f5fcb
```

Let's say, hypothetically, that work in commit 5295fe4 was done on a separate branch, then merged into master.  The resultant merge commit at 5497694 is what you want to release into production.

Once you pull down the repository with `git pull`, Git will include all of the work from that commit and a few others, which is to be expected - HEAD is a reference to the tip of your commit graph.  I'd avoid the use of the rebase flag here if you can; rebasing is powerful, but if this is done on a branch where many people can see it, it *could* lead to some heartache.

<sup>If you really do know what you're doing with rebase, then more power to you.  I'd recommend holding off until you feel fully comfortable with the nuances between Subversion and Git.</sup>

If you want to check out just *that* commit, then `git checkout 5497694` will suffice.  However, you're in a [detached HEAD](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) state - commits done here will create commit entries that aren't referenced by a branch, which makes it difficult to track. You can create a branch off of that commit and make changes to it there, of course.

If you want to formally declare this particular commit as releasable, then tagging it would be a better idea - run `git tag version-number 5497694` instead, and that will create an easier reference to this specific commit.

Ultimately, though, you want to just pull down the changes with `git pull`.  If your work depends on a specific check-in being present, `git pull` will sort you out.

As an aside, to answer an earlier question about pull vs checkout:  pull will update your local branch(es) with the changes from the remote server; checkout is generally used for creating branches.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed reply. I won't be committing in the master branch - only merging, so I suppose I don't need to do a git pull, simply git checkout will update my local repo to the required revison. If thats so, then how git checkout HEAD is different from git pull

Comment: So now I've got a bit more info - you're trying to rebase your work on top of master.  You shouldn't need to do anything at all, actually - when you're done with your work, merge it into master and deal with any conflicts that may arise.  As for your confusion - I'd encourage you to read [Git SCM](http://www.git-scm.com), which has a treasure trove of documentation, and a free ebook on Git.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds correct. You checkout to a version and then build your package from that. If you don't want artifcats, I can also recommend using the `archive` command to export the source tree as of commit `3ef0d` and then building the package from there.

Comment: Do I need to pull or is checkout enough. Is there any difference between two - checkout only and pull + checkout?

Comment: Pull fetches from a remote repository. checkout checkouts from the local repository into your working copy. I get the feeling that your basic git understanding is not very strong. I'd recommend that you spend a while going through the git book before seriously using it. It's not exactly the most intuitive of applications.