# How to restrictively update submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git project that I'd like to clone and update submodules on. I clone the project with

```
git clone --single-branch -b my_branch ssh://my_repo my_repo
```

I can init and pull submodules with

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

The problem I'm having is that all repository's git history (~ 1.3Gb) is being pulled with the update on each submodule. My `.gitmodules` file looks like

```
[submodule "mod_1"]
  path = path/to/mod_1
  url = my_repo
  branch = mod_1_branch
[submodule "mod_2"]
  path = path/to/mod_2
  url = my_repo
  branch = mod_2_branch
```

In the `git clone` command above I use `--single-branch` option which resolves the problem for the whole repository. As far as I know this option is not available for `git submodule update`.

How can I restrict submodules to pull only their branch history? Could there be an appropriate custom command (as described [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) under `update` > `custom command`)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately at the moment you cannot shallow fetch (`git fetch --depth=1`) a specified commit object.

However in Git 2.5+ (Q2 2015), fetching a single commit (without cloning the full repo) will be possible, through the new server-side config `uploadpack.allowReachableSHA1InWant`.

Its documentation says:

> uploadpack.allowReachableSHA1InWant::
>
> Allow `upload-pack` to accept a fetch request that asks for an
> object that is reachable from any ref tip. However, note that
> calculating object reachability is computationally expensive.
> Defaults to `false`.

For more details see [Pull a specific commit from a remote git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30701724/1104534).