# Send a pull request for a specific folder?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

In one commit, I have changed several files in several folders, say, `folderA`, `folderB`, and `folderC`. In `folderA` the changes are just adding comments and some code for printing intermediate results, which serve my own understanding. `folderB`, `folderC` are newly created, in there I have written some code for the project, now I want to only send a pull request for `folderB` and `folderC`, how would you do that?
Either working from the github webpage or the command line will be helpful.

Comment: When you do a pull request in Git, you pull the entire repository (both folders in your example given above).  Try looking into subrepositories.

Comment: You can fetch a specific commit - eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872486/pull-a-specific-commit-from-a-remote-git-repository But it will have all files present in that branch/commit. Also note the comments about how a pull isn't very 'expensive' as it's a delta (or "newly added code"); so as long as the local repo is similar to the changes it will be minimal transfer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, can you give an example?

Comment: Update your question with your specific scenario and I'll try to answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I have reedited my question, much appreciated.

Comment: I won't attempt an answer because my sense is that you are trying to use Git as if it is a file-based version control system, which it is not.  Please read up on some Git tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. You can send a pull request for a specific branch. The general way to do this is to put all the changes you want to on a topic branch and then to send a pull request for this branch.