# How to create a branch which can be synced to upstream master?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have made a fork from the project manager's master branch. According to my understanding, now the manager's master branch is `upstream/master`, the one I just forked is `origin/master`. I have made several changes to `origin/master`, some of the changes are just adding comments and code for printing intermediate results which serves my own understanding. But there are also changes which are newly written code. I committed all the changes in one single commit.  But I want to send a pull request to `upstream/master` only for the newly created code. I didn't have an easy solution for my goal, as stated in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31690827/2345484).

Now I want to create another branch called `Branch1` at `origin`, and this branch should be identical to the `upstream`, then I only commit the newly written code to `Branch1`, and send a pull request to `upstream` from this `Branch1`. Is this approach doable in current github system? If yes, can you please tell me how exactly this can be done.

**EDIT**

Based on a combination of the following comments, answers and my own searching, I solved the problem. What i did is the following:

1. `git checkout -b Branch1 upstream/master`, this will get an identical copy of `upstream/master` and make it as a new branch named `Branch1`
2. `git checkout Branch1`, and in file `config`,change the remote for `Branch1` to `origin`
3. `git checkout master somefolder`,  master should be `origin/master` at this point.
4. `git commit -m 'message'`
5. `git push`, `somefolder` will be pushed to `Branch1`

Comment: Did you actually fork it, or just clone it directly from his repository?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, yes, I did fork from his repository, not cloned it.

Comment: are you working with github?

Comment: @ben, yes, I am working with github.com

Comment: Isn't it just selecting the branch in the pulldown on the repository page,
and then clicking 'pull request'? Does [github help on pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/) clarify things?

Comment: @Kenney, how would you create a branch which is identical to `upstream/master` in the first place?

Comment: Well, you can do `git checkout -b Branch1 upstream/master`.

Comment: @Kenney, thanks, I will try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow when working with github is a mix of git commands and actions on github. Lets say your managers repo is at `https://github.com/manager/repo` and your name is `allanqunzi` on github.

1) Fork the repo on github so that you have the repo under `https://github.com/allenqunzi/repo`

2) Clone this repo to your machine with `git clone git@github.com:allenqunzi/repo.git`

3) the output of `git remote -v` should show only one remote with the name origin pointing to your repo at `git@github.com:allenqunzi/repo.git`

4) make your changes and commit them. push them with `git push origin master` to your repo

5) go to github and open a pull request. it should show up as a new pull request in your manager's repo. it says that you want someone to merge allenqunzi/repo master into manager/repo master.

6) someone accepts the PR and your code is finally into your managers repo.

**Optional Info A)**

If while you are working something cahnges in manager/repo and you need this locally, you can add the manager repo as a second remote with `git remote add upstream git@github.com:manager/repo.git`. `git remote -v` shows now two different remotes. Now you can do `git fetch upstream/master` and `git merge upstream/master` to update your local repo, then push it with `git push origin master` to update your repo on github.

**Optional Info B)**

You can also add commits in a different branch, push this branch and open a PR from this branch to the master branch of your managers repo.

**Optional Info C)**

If you just want to add certain files/commits to the managers repo, create a new branch locally. Then cherry-pick all the commits into this branch. Or copy all files you want to change in it, then make a new commit. Push this branch and open a pull request with this branch (see B) for more)

**Further readings**

Two resources are maybe helpful too (they explain kind of the same but maybe a bit more clear ;))

"Fork a repo" https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/

"Syncing a fork" https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/

Comment: My problem is step 4. I have made changes in one single commit to `origin/master`, among these changes there are some I don't want to pull request, and there are also some I want to pull request. Right now I can not select which specific file to pull request, I can only pull request all the changes I made.

Comment: added Optional Info C. this should help