# How to pull a specific commit from GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I realize there are similar answers, such as the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872486/pull-a-specific-commit-from-a-remote-git-repository), but these expect that you know the structure of GitHub commits and branches, and I don't.

So my question is if I want to pull a commit `12fds123nfd1123sefs12` from branch `master` on GitHub, what is the `git fetch` command?

For clarity, I mean I want to pull all commits up to a given commit.

Comment: Can you do `git fetch && git checkout 12fds123nfd1123sefs12`? I don't think you can retrieve an individual commit, since it is based on all the commits that went before it.

Comment: how about "`git show 12fds123nfd1123sefs12 `"?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Tell us why you need to pull this specific commit

Comment: Hmm, there is something on your linked question about getting single commits though - [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30701724/472495). It's a `fetch` with a depth of 1.

Comment: @halfer but that supposes GitHub has set the config `uploadpack.allowReachableSHA1InWant` (and has a Git 2.5). That isn't sure at all.

Comment: @zaratustra because some dumbass committed broken code afterwards and i need to update a customer to the latest code base before the break

Comment: -1: I think you are mixing terms. Are you sure you want to _pull_ the specific commit and not _checkout_ it? Also keep in mind that commits in Git don’t belong to branches, they are absolute. A branch is just a pointer to a commit.

Comment: Matthew, all you need to do is to pull master, checkout to a hash prior to the break, and branch at that point. You can then deploy the branch.

Comment: @VonC, thanks - ah, that sounds like a server-wide setting, fair enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have at least two ways to achieve that: the first one is to remove all the commits that are after the desired commit. [Interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Reordering-Commits) will help you:

```
$ git rebase 12fds123nfd1123sefs12 -i
```

You will see a text editor, you have to remove everything in it, then save it and forcely update the remote branch:

```
$ git push origin master -f
```

The second way is to create a branch based on the desired commit and then release this branch:

```
$ git checkout -b fixedmaster 12fds123nfd1123sefs12
```

Now you have the `fixedmaster` branch that doesn't have any bad commits. You can release it.

Comment: Thus spuke zaratustra. #clever

Comment: To remove all commits after a given SHA1, us `git reset --hard sha1`.  `git rebase -i` won't do the trick, since removing everything will abort the interactive rebase.  (Moreover, `git reset` is made exactly for this purpose and much more convenient to use.)