# How do I check out a specific commit from Github?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to checkout `https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/commit/54a6fa4542a4ae26d5a8155b63a50701ab69c1f8`.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa.git
Cloning into 'Zappa'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 15029, done.
remote: Total 15029 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 15029
Receiving objects: 100% (15029/15029), 4.71 MiB | 932.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (11418/11418), done.
$ cd Zappa
$ git checkout 54a6fa4542a4ae26d5a8155b63a50701ab69c1f8
fatal: reference is not a tree: 54a6fa4542a4ae26d5a8155b63a50701ab69c1f8
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it shouldn't be an issue, can you show the ``git status``?

Comment: What does `git show 54a6fa45` result in?

Comment: `fatal: ambiguous argument '54a6fa45': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: If you get this error that means you are referring to a git hash that does not exist anymore.  Try `git log ` and look if you can see that commit hash

Comment: I can't find that commit locally, but I can see it (as can everyone) if you go to https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/commit/54a6fa4542a4ae26d5a8155b63a50701ab69c1f8

Comment: It's likely that commit was unreachable so it was removed from the repo, but for completeness github still has it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to fetch commit from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093393/unable-to-fetch-commit-from-github)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that `54a6fa4542a4ae26d5a8155b63a50701ab69c1f8` is only half-in the repository at `https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa`.

That is, if you clone `https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa`, you get a valid repository with a bit under 3000 commits in it.  `54a6fa4542a4ae26d5a8155b63a50701ab69c1f8` is *not* one of those commits.

In fact, `54a6fa4542a4ae26d5a8155b63a50701ab69c1f8` is a commit in *another* repository.  You can see this in `https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/pull/1762`, which displays, among other things:

```
 Open   purificant wants to merge 1 commit into Miserlou:master from purificant:py37
```

So this commit is more properly in a fork owned by `purificant` under branch name `py37` (hover over some of the labels and you'll see a bit more detail in pop-ups).

However, once someone makes a pull request on GitHub, those commits *are* available via the target repository as well.  It just takes a bit of trickery:

```
git fetch origin refs/pull/1762/head:refs/heads/pr1762
```

Now `git show 54a6fa4542a4ae26d5a8155b63a50701ab69c1f8` and `git checkout 54a6fa4542a4ae26d5a8155b63a50701ab69c1f8` work.

```
$ git checkout 54a6fa4542a4ae26d5a8155b63a50701ab69c1f8
Note: checking out '54a6fa4542a4ae26d5a8155b63a50701ab69c1f8'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 54a6fa4 python3.7 support
```

(It's not clear to me how someone who is not me would figure this out. :-) )

(The raw name `pr1762` I used here is not a good one, I've edited it to read `refs/heads/pr1762` instead.)

Comment: Also this link : https://help.github.com/articles/commit-exists-on-github-but-not-in-my-local-clone/

Comment: @HRK44: yes, though those are for commits that *were* in a repository but are now gone, whereas this is for a commit that's sort of halfway-there. It may eventually be all the way there, or not, depending on what the owner of the repository does.

Comment: So the confusion is due to Github rewriting their URL as if the commit comes directly from the repo...

Comment: @HRK44: not exactly: *while the pull request is present*, the commit *is* in the repo, it's just under a reference that `git clone` does not clone. As soon as the pull request is closed, the reference is dropped. At that point, if the commit *isn't* reachable from some other reference, it will be garbage collected, but until then you can still get to it by URL. That's why I called it "half in": it's there, tentatively, until the PR is closed, at which time it may or may not still be there.