# Unable to fetch code from git repository for a specific SHA in ansible

Tags: git, ansible

I want to fetch code using a particular SHA-id.This is what I am trying

```
- git: 
        repo: http://<git-url>/Vara-Internal/mongo-db-dev.git
        dest: "{{ app_path }}/{{ app_dir }}"
        version: "{{ GIT_TAG }}"
        refspec: '+refs/heads/{{ GIT_TAG }}:refs/remotes/origin/{{ GIT_TAG }}'
        update: yes
        force: true
      register: cloned
```

It throwing me this error

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["/usr/bin/git", "fetch", "--tags", "origin", "+refs/heads/dbde451f203a112d0838fb09bc19ed28bd231e6e:refs/remotes/origin/dbde451f203a112d0838fb09bc19ed28bd231e6e"], "failed": true, "msg": "Failed to download remote objects and refs:  fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/dbde451f203a112d0838fb09bc19ed28bd231e6e\n"}
```

Comment: Q: does :"dbde451f203a112d0838fb09bc19ed28bd231e6e" exist in your .git objects folder?

Comment: yes.it is my old deployment sha-id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note: I know very little about ansible, being just a casual user.)

Most (but not all) Git *servers* will not let you retrieve objects by hash IDs at all.  Most servers require that the object have a name, such as `refs/heads/master` (branch `master`) or `refs/tags/v1.1` (the tag named `v1.1`).

If a server does allow retrieval by hash ID (see [VonC's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30701724/1256452)), you *must not* qualify the hash ID: it's not `refs/heads/dbde451f203a112d0838fb09bc19ed28bd231e6e` bit rather simply `dbde451f203a112d0838fb09bc19ed28bd231e6e`.  That would become the *`src`* part of a *`src:dst`* refspec.

Typically you would use a tag name here, not a hash ID, but if your server does allow retrieval by hash ID, the refspec line would logically have to read:

```
refspec: '+{{ GIT_TAG }}:refs/remotes/origin/some-particular-name'
```

as it is not a good idea to use hash IDs as names (for several reasons, the main one being that you will confuse humans).

Comment: could you please explain what is the use + sign in refspec?

Comment: The leading `+` means the same as `--force`: overwrite the destination reference even if the normal rules would disallow this.

Comment: Actually i need this to revert out changes in last deployment.and when i used +{{ GIT_TAG }}:refs/heads/{{ GIT_TAG }}:refs/remotes/origin/{{ GIT_TAG }} it throwing me Invalid refspec error.

Comment: It's possible that ansible is overly picky about the form of refspec, but it's *far* more likely that your server *does not accept hash IDs*.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i took secondary way to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I used indirect method to the same.I have save commit ids in a file and added following code

```
- name: Reverting Changes
      command: "git reset --hard {{ GIT_TAG }}"
      args:
        chdir: "{{ app_path }}/{{ app_dir }}"
      when: build_type  == "revert"
```

i.e. I took an extra variable which is build_type and checked whether this is for **revert** the changes.If it is then i read the commit id from my git information file and hard reset my branch.