# Is it possible to fetch commit by commit from remote in git?

Tags: git

I have an empty git repo and I want to fetch commit by commit from a remote repo. For example, I do

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
git pull --no-edit -s recursive -X theirs . 1da177e4c3f41524e886b7f1b8a0c1fc7321cac2
```

However, doing so gives me an error `fatal: no matching remote head`. I'm wondering if fetching commit one by one from scratch is possible using git?

Put the question in another way. I want to simulate `git clone` but instead of `git clone` fetching all commits, I want to get commit one by one, which allows me to perform some other work in-between.

Thanks!

Comment: even it it were possible, what do you want to achieve that is not possible to do by fetching everything at once?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve specific commit from a remote Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872486/retrieve-specific-commit-from-a-remote-git-repository)

Comment: @eftshift0 I'm doing a scientific experiment with this setup is a must and I don't think my purpose is relevant to this question.

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink Thanks for the suggestion. I don't think my question is duplicate because I tried to start from scratch and fetch commit one by one (possibly, no `fetch` or `clone` involved)

Comment: I believe that you may have confused the purpose of fetch and pull. If you are wanting to see where individual files are at for a commit, use a pull, pointing to a specific change set, otherwise, you can fetch to have git's knowledge of the current origin updated to have everything that is currently in origin.

Comment: @dmoore1181 Thanks for the comment. I want to do `git pull` to simulate patching source files.

Comment: You said you're doing a scientific experiment, however it's unclear what you're trying to test. Why would `git fetch origin` followed by `git cherry-pick <commit>` not work, where cherry-picking actually is "patching source files"? You should probably add those details to the description.

Comment: Also, note that `git pull` is just `git fetch` followed by `git merge`. You can simply fetch everything at once, then merge one commit at a time the way you would have `pull`ed one commit at a time, without bothering to `fetch` again. This will be much faster as you'll skip the "contact the other Git" step. Meanwhile, note that the remote name `.` means "myself", so as expressed, this says to create an empty repository, then fill it from itself, which won't do much good either.