# Syncing my fork of repo with original repo

Tags: git, fork, git-fork

I see a lot of posts about this and I know the general answer, executing this from my fork's local repo:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/abcd/efgh.git
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
(resolve merge conflicts)
git commit -m "my message"
git push
```

But I have a  couple of questions  beyong the general case.

1. When I do the `git push`, why do i not have to specify with remote I am pushing to? or do I?
2. Also, how can i get a particular commit id from `upstream` instead of the latest commit which is what I would get when I do `fetch upstream`?

Comment: 1. You can choose to mention the remote you are pushing to. If not mentioned it uses the tracked remote for that local branch.

Comment: 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872486/retrieve-specific-commit-from-a-remote-git-repository

Comment: 1. About bare `git push`: see [`git config push.default`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushdefault). Default value is `simple`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/abcd/efgh.git
git fetch upstream
git checkout 1q2w3e4r5t -b giveItABranchName
git checkout main
git merge giveItABranchName
(resolve merge conflicts)
git commit -m "my message"
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `git push` without any further arguments will use the branches' upstream to determine where to push. If you're on a branch, then `git status` will show you current upstream for this branch (if any).
   You can `git branch --unset-upstream` or `git --set-upstream=newupstream/example`
   If you want to push your currently checked-out branch to a specific place, e.g. upstream you can just do `git push upstream master`
2. Specify the commit you want to fetch: e.g. `git fetch upstream 61586219a7450af5a72f857db62d9a89ad9cc38f`
   The fetched commit can be accessed in git commands using `FETCH_HEAD`. E.g. `git log FETCH_HEAD`.

Note: Not all repositories allow fetching arbitrary commits. E.g. they may only permit fetching named branches and pull requests ([github](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally)).